# Calculator with significant figures

Tags: java, floating-point, calculator, interpreter

I'm writing a small scientific programming language, and I thought my first step would be to write a calculator with built in [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures). I wrote this with [JParsec](http://jparsec.codehaus.org/) for the lexing and parsing. I was wondering if there were any problems you could see in my code. I'm fairly skeptical of my own use of `BigDecimal`.

**Calculator.java**

```
public class Calculator {

enum BinaryOperator implements Binary<SigDec> {
    PLUS {
      public SigDec map(SigDec a, SigDec b) {
        return a.add(b);
      }
    },
    MINUS {
      public SigDec map(SigDec a, SigDec b) {
        return a.sub(b);
      }
    },
    MUL {
      public SigDec map(SigDec a, SigDec b) {
        return a.mul(b);
      }
    },
    DIV {
      public SigDec map(SigDec a, SigDec b) {
        return a.div(b);
      }
    }
  }

  enum UnaryOperator implements Unary<SigDec> {
    NEG {
      public SigDec map(SigDec n) {
        return n.mul(-1);
      }
    }
  }

  static final Parser<SigDec> NUMBER = Terminals.DecimalLiteral.PARSER.map(new Map<String, SigDec>() {
      public SigDec map(String s) {
          return new SigDec(new BigDecimal(s), SigDec.significantDigits(s));
      }
    });

  private static final Terminals OPERATORS = Terminals.operators("+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")");

  static final Parser<Void> IGNORED =
      Parsers.or(Scanners.JAVA_LINE_COMMENT, Scanners.JAVA_BLOCK_COMMENT, Scanners.WHITESPACES).skipMany();

  static final Parser<?> TOKENIZER =
      Parsers.or(Terminals.DecimalLiteral.TOKENIZER, OPERATORS.tokenizer());

  static Parser<?> term(String... names) {
    return OPERATORS.token(names);
  }

  static final Parser<BinaryOperator> WHITESPACE_MUL =  term("+", "-", "*", "/").not().retn(BinaryOperator.MUL);

  static <T> Parser<T> op(String name, T value) {
    return term(name).retn(value);
  }

  static Parser<SigDec> calculator(Parser<SigDec> atom) {
    Parser.Reference<SigDec> ref = Parser.newReference();
    Parser<SigDec> unit = ref.lazy().between(term("("), term(")")).or(atom);
    Parser<SigDec> parser = new OperatorTable<SigDec>()
        .infixl(op("+", BinaryOperator.PLUS), 10)
        .infixl(op("-", BinaryOperator.MINUS), 10)
        .infixl(op("*", BinaryOperator.MUL).or(WHITESPACE_MUL), 20)
        .infixl(op("/", BinaryOperator.DIV), 20)
        .prefix(op("-", UnaryOperator.NEG), 30)
        .build(unit);
    ref.set(parser);
    return parser;
  }

  public static final Parser<SigDec> CALCULATOR = calculator(NUMBER).from(TOKENIZER, IGNORED);

  public static void main(String[] args){
      //testing
      System.out.println(CALCULATOR.parse("1.1 + 23232.220"));
  }
}
```

**SigDec.java**

```
public class SigDec{
    //better name for this class maybe? SigDecimal? 

    public final BigDecimal num;
    public final int precision;

    public SigDec(String str, int precision){
        num = SigDec.roundToSignificantFigures(new BigDecimal(str), precision);
        this.precision = precision;
    }

    public SigDec(double doub, int precision){
        num = new BigDecimal(SigDec.roundToSignificantFigures(doub, precision));
        this.precision = precision;
    }
    public SigDec(BigDecimal bd, int precision){
        num = SigDec.roundToSignificantFigures(bd, precision);
        this.precision = precision;
    }
    public SigDec mul(SigDec other) {
        return new SigDec(num.multiply(other.num), Math.min(other.precision, this.precision));
    }
    public SigDec mul(int i) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(i);
        return new SigDec(num.multiply(bd), Math.min(this.precision, getSignificantDigits(bd)));
    }
    public SigDec div(SigDec other) {
        return new SigDec(num.divide(other.num), Math.min(other.precision, this.precision));
    }
    public SigDec add(SigDec other) {
        return new SigDec(num.add(other.num), Math.min(other.precision, this.precision));
    }
    public SigDec sub(SigDec other) {
        return new SigDec(num.subtract(other.num), Math.min(other.precision, this.precision));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return num.toString();
    }
    public static int significantDigits(String s) {
        //counts trailing zeroes
        if(s.contains(".")){
            int zeroes = 0;
            for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(s.charAt(i) != '0'){
                    break;
                }
                zeroes++;
            }
            //will this be tail call optimized?
            return zeroes + getSignificantDigits(new BigDecimal(s));
        }else{
            return getSignificantDigits(new BigDecimal(s));
        }
    }
    public static int getSignificantDigits(BigDecimal input) {
            input = input.stripTrailingZeros();
            return input.scale() < 0
                ? input.precision() - input.scale()
                : input.precision(); 
        }

    public static BigDecimal roundToSignificantFigures(BigDecimal bd, int precision) {

        if(bd.equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            return BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }

        final double d = Math.ceil(Math.log10(bd.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 ? bd.negate().doubleValue(): bd.doubleValue()));
        final int power = precision - (int) d;

        final double magnitude = Math.pow(10, power);
        final long shifted = Math.round(bd.doubleValue() * magnitude);

        return BigDecimal.valueOf(shifted/magnitude);
    }
    public static double roundToSignificantFigures(double num, int precision) {

        if(num == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        final double d = Math.ceil(Math.log10(num < 0 ? -num: num));
        final int power = precision - (int) d;

        final double magnitude = Math.pow(10, power);
        final long shifted = Math.round(num*magnitude);

        return shifted/magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the naming of WHITESPACE_MUL nor why it returns MUL

Comment: That's just so I can write this: `3 (6 + 5)` instead of `3 * (6 + 5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have some simple style recommendations for now, so here goes:

1. In `SigDec.java`, add some newlines between methods (or at least be consistent in how you deal with whitespace between methods). Also, you have an extra tab before the ending brace of `getSignificantDigits()`. Also, in both `roundToSignificantFigures()` methods, you seem to have some inconsistent newlines between variable declarations.
2. Perhaps I am being too strict, but I really think that it's important to give your variables real names instead of `a`, `b`, or `d`. For example, in your `BinaryOperator` `enum`'s `MUL` I would call `a` `factor1` and `b` `factor2`. It might be worth getting a second opinion on this one because they are really simple methods, but I would at least encourage you to change some of the names like `s`, `bd`, and `d` in your `SigDec` class. (`i` is okay since it is the counter for a `for` loop.)

Comment: I don't find `factor1` and `factor2` more descriptive than `a` and `b`. The only missing thing is Javadoc to say, for instance, which one is substracted from the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right to use `BigDecimal` if you don't want errors caused by floating-point precision and want to allow any kind of input.

I find your code pretty good, a few comments:

- `SignedDecimal` would be much better than `SigDec`
- The name `precision` is incorrect. A precision means means that `x == y iff abs(x-y) < precision` ; but in your case precision = 2 means a precision of 0.01. BigDecimal uses the term `significantDigit` and that's much more accurate.
- Javadoc is missing, as you know
- code formatting is inconsistent. Blank lines usually code around methods more than within them.